# openid RP not maintaining session between calls to provider

Tags: session, openid, session-state, httpsession, openid4java

I have a working "relying party" app that uses a thirdparty `OpenID` provider for login. However, if I attempt login in with a "home grown" `OpenID` provider which uses the `org.openid4java.server.SampleServer`, the session is not maintained between `beginConsumption` and `endConsumption`.

I can see successful discovery and association, with this being reached in springs `OpenID4JavaConsumer`:

```
DiscoveryInformation information = consumerManager.associate(discoveries);
req.getSession().setAttribute(DISCOVERY_INFO_KEY, information);
```

But after my OP does authentication and `response.sendRedirect`'s back to the RP, a new session is started there and I get failure in at `OpenID4JavaConsumer.endConsumption`:

```
DiscoveryInformation discovered = 
    (DiscoveryInformation) request.getSession().getAttribute(DISCOVERY_INFO_KEY);

if (discovered == null) {
    throw new OpenIDConsumerException("DiscoveryInformation is not available. Possible causes are lost session or replay attack");
}
```

What is causing this new session to be created and how can I keep my old session?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to move past this with this in the OP code:

```
Cookie sessionCookie = getSessionCookie(request.getCookies());
if (sessionCookie != null) {
    response.addCookie(sessionCookie);
}
String url = response.encodeRedirectURL(responseBody);
response.sendRedirect(url);
```

and

```
private Cookie getSessionCookie(Cookie[] cookies) {
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        if (cookie.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("JSESSIONID")) {
            return cookie;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

On the surface this makes sense, but still feels mysterious that the OpenId SampleServer class or docs didn't mention this as a possible need, which leaves me wondering if my set up is "wrong" in some other way. Onward...